# I'm facing a bug which i could not fix it - Buy_Item in shop website

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

Well what i'm trying to do, is to make that button when inserting on it , run buy_item.php , i'm tottality lost ,i want to make the script check the amount (wallet money ) of user and check the price of the clicked button of the item (every item is related to buy button) and if they have enough money it buys . But scrript is not working , 
the button
*UPDATED*

```
    <?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "localhost", "localhost", "localhost");
if ($conn->connect_error) { 
 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 } 
   $sql = "SELECT id,type, price,seller FROM items 

$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<tr>";
echo '<td><form action="buy_item.php"><button>a</button></form></td>'; 
        echo "</tr>";

}
echo "</table>";
} else { echo "0 results"; }
$conn->close();
?>
</table>
```

The buy_item.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "localhost", "localhost", "localhost");
if ($conn->connect_error) { 
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql = "SELECT price,username,amount FROM items,users WHERE username = '" . 
$_SESSION['username'] . "' ";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   if   $row["amount"]  >= $row["price"]  {
      $newAmount =  $row["amount"]  - $row["price"] ;
        header("location:/quickshops/seller/tutoadd.php");

        } 
        else
            {
                                echo "You got no enough money buddy.";
      } 
     }
```

Comment: You don't pass any values through the form, so how do you check what they want to purchase?

Comment: `if   $row["amount"]  >= $row["price"]  {`- This is also missing the parentheses and should cause a syntax error.

Comment: How can i do it so ? atleast pass the price ? or idk the id of item

Comment: Pass a value through a hidden input and send it over POST method

Comment: btw values are from db not written already selected

Comment: You should read the manual about dealing with forms: http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php